# Reading 12bit little endian integers from can frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, endianness, can-bus

I am reading in a series of CAN BUS frames from python-can represented as hex strings, e.g. '9819961F9FFF7FC1' and I know the values in each frame are laid out as follows:

```
Signal Startbit Length
A      0        8
B      8        4
C      12       4
D      16       12
E      28       12
F      40       16
G      56       4
```

With each value being an unsigned integer, with little endian byte order. Where I am struggling is how to deal with the 12 bit signals, and how to do it fast as this will be running in real time. As far as I understand struct.unpack only supports 1,2,4, and 8 byte integers. The Bitstring package also only supports whole-byte bitstrings when you specify the endianness.

I clearly don't understand binary well enough to do it by manipulating the bits directly because I have been tearing my hair out trying to get sensible values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to decode the frame successfully and reasonably quickly with the [bitstruct](https://github.com/eerimoq/bitstruct) library, which can handle values with any number of bits, as in the code below.

However I found I also had to swap the location of the hex characters if two signals are present on the same byte, as in the [CAN frame layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdnRN.jpg). I'm still not sure why, but it does work.

```
swapped_frame = frame[0:2] + frame[3] + frame[2] + frame[4:6] + frame[7] + \
frame[6] + frame[8:]
ba = bytearray(swapped_frame.decode('hex'))
A,B,C,D,E,F,G = bitstruct.unpack('<u8u4u4u12u12u16u4', ba)
```